# Bringing data from other workbooks - goal not accomplished in nested if

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have this code in which I am bringing data from several workbooks into one. The data of each workbook needs to be added into a specific range depending on the source. To do this I nested some IFs with the partial name of the file as condition and giving the action of sending the values to the desired range, but when I run the code it only opens all the workbooks without performing any action. I already did some research and did not find anything to help me with my problem

```
Sub Update_Database()

Dim directory As String
Dim fileName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    directory = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
End With

fileName = Dir(directory & "\", vbReadOnly)

Dim mwb As Workbook
Set mwb = Workbooks("OEE_Database_Final.xlsm")

Do While fileName <> ""
    On Error GoTo ProcExit
    With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=directory & "\" & fileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        If (fileName = "NOM*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O9:Z290").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O9:Z290")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "SZE*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O291:Z537").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O291:Z537")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "VEC*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O538:Z600").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O538:Z600")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "KAY*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O601:Z809").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O601:Z809")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "BBL*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O810:Z952").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O810:Z952")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "POG*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O953:Z1037").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O953:Z1037")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "SC1*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1038:Z1159").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1038:Z1159")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "SC2*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1160:Z1200").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1160:Z1200")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "SLP*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1201:Z1263").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1201:Z1263")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "UIT*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1264:Z1348").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1264:Z1348")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "ANE*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1349:Z1823").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1349:Z1823")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "HAL*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O1824:Z2077").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O1824:Z2077")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "SHX*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2078:Z2242").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2078:Z2242")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "BAY*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2243:Z2415").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2243:Z2415")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "TAM*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2416:Z2522").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2416:Z2522")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "PUC*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2523:Z2607").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2523:Z2607")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "JOF*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2608:Z2648").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2608:Z2648")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ElseIf (fileName = "MAV*.xlsx") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O2649:Z2945").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O2649:Z2945")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    End With
    fileName = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


ProcExit:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: `Select Case` will make this cleaner

Comment: you cannot compare with  = and partial name, use [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator)

Comment: you are also using a `With` block but not taking advantage of it's use. Delete all instances of `ActiveWorkbook` (keep the `.`) and your code will run faster and more efficiently.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Currently, you are assigning some values to a range in the newly opened workbook and then close it without saving. If the code runs as presented, there would be literally no observable change. Is your intention to write all values to `mwb.Sheets("Database")`?

Comment: Also: Is there an error (as indicated in the question title) or does the code just not accomplish your goal? If the former, please include all the details about the error.

Comment: @Inarion hi, yes my intention is to write all values to `mwb.Sheets("Database")` and there is no error I made a mistake on what I wrote, I already edited the title

Comment: In this case, please take a very close look at what your code is doing: `ActiveWorkbook.[...].Value = mwb.[...].Value` takes the values **from** `mwb` and writes them **to** `ActiveWorkbook`. Isn't this exactly contrary to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the snippet

```
With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=directory & "\" & fileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    If (fileName = "NOM*.xlsx") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("O9:Z290").Value = mwb.Sheets("Database").Range("O9:Z290")
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End With
```

you're opening a file, writing some values **from** `mbw.Sheets("Database")` **to** it and then close the just modified file *without saving*.

From your comment it seems your intention is to do the opposite:

```
Dim mwb As Workbook
Set mwb = Workbooks("OEE_Database_Final.xlsm")
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = mwb.Sheets("Database")

Do While Filename <> ""
    On Error GoTo ProcExit
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=directory & "\" & Filename, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        Select Case True
            Case Filename Like "NOM*.xlsx"
                Ws.Range("O9:Z290").Value = .Sheets("Database").Range("O9:Z290").Value
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            Case Filename Like "SZE*.xlsx"
                ' Code for this case
            ' Other cases...
            Case Else
                ' Put code here that is executed if none of the previous names has been matched
                ' or remove 'Case Else' if you don't want anything to happen then
        End Select
    End With
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Some things to note:

- I've implemented the suggestion from [Shai Rado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592785/7778672) to make use of the `Like` operator in a `Select Case` structure
- I've assigned a new `Worksheet` variable as such `Set Ws = mwb.Sheets("Database")` - this shortens the lines and makes it easier to refer to a different sheet, should requirements change (one change as opposed to ~20 changes)
- The `With` block now is actually taken advantage of. When you do `With Workbooks.Open`, VBA provides you with an implicit reference to that workbook. So there is no need to refer to `ActiveWorkbook`. A simple `.` is enough. Also it removes that brittle dependency on having the *right* workbook active at the right time. (Imagine what happens if for whatever reason the `ActiveWorkbook` changes half-way through your macro... Not a likely scenario, I'll give you that.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can "cheat" a little to get away with `Select Case`.

In order to use the `Like` with `Select`, you use `Select Case True` and then nest your scenraios using `Like` and wild card `*`.

**code**

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=directory & "\" & Filename, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    Select Case True
        Case Filename Like "NOM*.xlsx"

        Case Filename Like "SZE*.xlsx"

        Case Filename Like "VEC*.xlsx"

        Case Filename Like "KAY*.xlsx"

        Case Filename Like "BBL*.xlsx"

        ' put all other scenarios down here....


    End Select

End With
```

**Note**: if all your files you are trying t check are excel files, so you don't need to add the `.xlsx` extension, just use `NOM*`, `SZE*`, etc.

Comment: this isn't "cheating" at all. it's a valid and smart use of the coding language :)

Comment: @Gerardo Lopez , you’re welcome :) If helped your post you can mark as “ANSWER” by clicking the gray check mark in the left side of my answe, it will turn green